# Replacing with backreference in TextMate issue

Tags: regex, textmate

I am using TextMate to replace expression `[my_expression]` consisting in characters between open and closed brackets by `{my_expression}`; so I tried to replace

```
\[[^]]*\]
```

by

```
{$1}
```

The regex matches the correct expression, but the replacement gives `{$1}`, so that the variable is not recognised. Can someone has an idea ?

Comment: You forgot to escape a character, use `\[[^\]]*\]`. You also need a capture group, so use `\[([^\]]*)\]`

Comment: escaping `]` is not required though

Comment: You can simplify your regex to \[(.*?)\]. the ? after the * makes it non-greedy since i [^]] is kinda hard on the eyes... and yes, you need the () to specify a capture group that TextMate can recognize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape a character, `[^]]` should be `[^\]]`.

You also need a capture group. `$1` is [back-referencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) the **`1st` Capture Group**, and you had no capture groups, so use the following Regex:

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

This adds `()` around `[^\]]*`, so the data inside the `[]` is captured. For more info, see this page on [Capture Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

However, this RegEx is shorter:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Also substituting with `{$1}`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/zB8sI2/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group `(...)`:

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

The `$1` is a backreference to the text enclosed with `[...]`.

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xE8oB5/2) and also [*Numbered Backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Also, the [TextMate docs](https://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions):

> **1. Syntax elements**
>   
>   `(...)`   group
>
> **20.4.1 Captures**
>   
>   To reference a capture, use `$n` where n is the **capture register number**. Using `$0` means the entire match.

And also:

> - If you want to use `[`, `-`, `]` as a normal character in a character class, you should escape these characters by `\`.